# How to convert single column to multiple columns using spark dataframe

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe like below, I need to show first row as header with corresponding values:

```
+------------------------+
|cleaned                 |
+------------------------+
|id,name,salary,dept     |
|1,John,10000,IT         |
|2,Mindhack Diva,20000,IT|
|3,Michel,30000,IT       |
|4,Ryan,40000,IT         |
|5,Sahoo,10000,IT        |
+------------------------+
```

And I need output like the dataframe below:

```
+---+-------------+------+----+
| id|         name|salary|dept|
+---+-------------+------+----+
|  1|         John| 10000|  IT|
|  2|Mindhack Diva| 20000|  IT|
|  3|       Michel| 30000|  IT|
|  4|         Ryan| 40000|  IT|
|  5|        Sahoo| 10000|  IT|
+---+-------------+------+----+
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd advice to clean the input before reading so you don't bother with the first row, especially if you read a csv, there are header and delimiter options to help you achieve exactly what you're asking without extra code. Now if you still want to handle your specific case it's possible.

It's hard to determine the first row of a dataset as the processing is distributed and your data partitioned... So you can't really rely on first() method unless you're in one partition.

If you're sure that the "header" is always the same you could just filter it out first, then split your data into columns, so something like that using Spark SQL split function:

```
df.where(col("cleaned") !== "id,name,salary,dept") // filter the "header" row first
  .select(split(col("cleaned"),",").getItem(0).as("id"), \ 
          split(col("cleaned"),",").getItem(1).as("name"), \     
          split(col("cleaned"),",").getItem(2).as("salary"), \ 
          split(col("cleaned"),",").getItem(3).as("dept"))
```

Of course, you can do it in two steps, and / or more intelligently but this is the principle.

See more: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.split.html